# only printing first if statement python

Tags: python, if-statement

I did very simple code,  I literally just started python but I created some IF and elif statements and it always, prints the first If statement, sorry for bothering people with this petty problem. I tried to search and couldn't find my problem due my lack of experience.

```
    name = input ("what is your name")
if name == ("x") or ("y"):
    print ("Hello")
elif name == "n" or name == "m" or name ==  "N" or name == "M":
    print  ("a")
else:
    print ("b")
```

Comment: Show the problematic code.

Comment: `if name == 'x' or name == 'y'`, better still `if name in ('x', 'y')`

Comment: This might help to understand: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/operators_precedence_example.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
 if name == "x" or name == "y"
```

works

Comment: Please do not answer duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

your first statement is equivalent to

```
if (name == 'x') or ('y')
```

NOT

```
if (name == 'x') or (name == 'y')
```

and

```
if 'y'
```

is always true

so your code shortcuts and uses the first condition

Comment: Please do not answer duplicates.